# Send cookie between same domains of second level

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch

I have two urls: one.example.com and two.example.com

How to make fetch request from one.example.com to two.example.com which will send cookies also? Request looks like this:

```
fetch('two.example.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to share cookies between two subdomains, you just have to modify the domain of your cookie so it starts with a dot

Eg:

Cookie domain `one.example.com` will be readable only by one.example.com

Cookie domain `.example.com` will be readable by every sub domains of example.com